# Ploblema al ejecutar el clasico programa: "hello world". En Win32 en nasm

Tags: windows, nasm

Estoy empezando a aprender nasm Y para aprender lo básico estoy haciendo un programa que muestre en la consola una oración. Pero al compilarlo me sale:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;ERROR;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;[17:53:11] Atención! Han ocurrido errores en la compilación:
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o:C:\Users\Usuario\A:(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle'
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o:C:\Users\Usuario\A:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `WriteConsoleA'
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o:C:\Users\Usuario\A:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `ExitProcess'
c:/program files/sasm/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

Y este es mi código:

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
NULL equ 0
extern ExitProcess, GetStdHandle,WriteConsoleA
section .data
msg db "hello world",13,10,0
msg.len equ $ -msg
section .bss
dummy resd 1

section .text
global _main
_main:
push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle
push 0
push dummy
push msg.len
push msg
push eax
call WriteConsoleA
push 0
call ExitProcess
```

Uso win32 y mi IDE es SASM en modo x86. No se donde esta el error pero sospecho que no existe:

```
GetStdHandle,WriteConsoleA,ExitProcess
```

Este código lo saque de esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575061/15154709

Y a ver tantos votos veo que soy el único con este problema.
Soy nuevo en lenguaje de ensamblador y todos los tutoriales que consigo o es para Linux o es para win64. Me ayudan.

Comment: Se que no es buena la pregunta. Yo nunca me he caracterisado por hacer una. Por favor pido pasiencia.

Comment: agrega el link a la otra respuesta

Comment: ¿El link no esta?

Comment: ¿Con qué comandos lo compilas y enlazas?

Comment: @abulafia La verdad no se. Pero mi ide hace estos comando al ejecutar el programa: Opciones de esamblador : -f win32 $Souce$ -l $LSTOUTPUT$ -o $PROGRAM.OBJ$
Opciones de linkeado : $PROGRAM.OBJ$ $MACRO.OBJ$ -g -o $PROGRAM$ -m32

Comment: La ruta de esamblador es: nasm y la del linkeador es: gcc

Answer (score 2):

En windows podemos usar una libreria
extandar de C para mostrar texto por pantalla usando la funcion `_printf`:

```
global _main
extern _printf
section .text
 push msg ; Insertamos la cadena a la pila
 call _printf ;Llamamos a _printf
 add esp,4 ;sumamos 4
ret ;retornamos al sistema
;Y por ultimos definimos msg
section .data
msg db "Hellow world",0
```

Y por ultimo ponemos el comando en la consola:

```
nasm -fwin32 helloworld.asm
gcc helloworld.obj
```

Enlaces externos:
[¿Cómo escribir hola mundo en ensamblador en Windows?](https://qastack.mx/programming/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Proba con el siguiente código

; Define variables in the data section

SECTION .DATA

```
hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
helloLen:  equ $-hello
```

; Code goes in the text section

SECTION .TEXT

```
   GLOBAL _start
```

_start:

```
mov eax,4            ; 'write' system call = 4
mov ebx,1            ; file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
mov ecx,hello        ; string to write
mov edx,helloLen     ; length of string to write
int 80h              ; call the kernel

; Terminate program

mov eax,1            ; 'exit' system call
mov ebx,0            ; exit with error code 0
int 80h              ; call the kernel
```

Comment: Solo para LINUX es la solución.:) Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

También me estoy iniciando en Ensamblador, estuve leyendo un poco, a ver si te ayuda:

- hay que tener claro que existe código ensamblador para x86, 32 y 64, también existe código ensamblador para windows, linux, mac, y lo último existen compiladores nasm, gas, fasm y masm.
- según veo tu código es para 32 bits, lo indica el registro que estás usando "eax"
- configura nasm para 32 bits
- también la sección de código debe iniciar con la etiqueta main:

Prueba con eso.

Comment: Nasm también sirve para Windows. Ojo: x86 es 32bits, y x64 o x86-64 es para 64bits, y también existe el 16bits... La diferencia mas que nada son los registros usados... Gracias por la respuesta. Me gustaría que la mejores, agregarle una solución al problema o un código para mostrar algo por consola, esto para que no termine cerrada. Recomiendo leer: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).